# Error: No handler for requested intent at DialogFlow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Here's my inline editor. I'm trying to insert data into cloud firestore and it doesn't work.

I'm confused because i created manual intents but there's also agent.add, so i didn't use agent.add for my reply intent because i already created one manually.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  projectId: 'your_project_id'
  //databaseURL: 'your_database_url'
});
const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  function tambahHandler(agent) {
    const barang = agent.parameters.barang;

    const jumlah = agent.parameters.jumlah;
    const satuan = agent.parameters.satuan;
    const kat = agent.parameters.kategori;
    db.collection('barang').add({
      nama: barang
    });
    agent.add(`Ini, ${barang}`);"
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('tambah kategori', tambahHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**Diagnostic Info**

```
{
  "responseId": "ed0edac3-8263-45b6-b330-eb157ecfe576-7ef0c984",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "buah",
    "action": "insert_barang.insert_barang-custom.tambahbarang-custom.tambahjumlah-custom",
    "parameters": {
      "kategori": [
        "buah"
      ]
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Baik, 1 kilo apel berhasil ditambahkan ke buah",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Baik, 1 kilo apel berhasil ditambahkan ke buah"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/project_id/locations/global/agent/sessions/53916acd-7261-6012-5130-b1ace7661703/contexts/tambahjumlah-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "jumlah": 1,
          "jumlah.original": "1",
          "satuan": "kilo",
          "kategori": [
            "buah"
          ],
          "kategori.original": [
            "buah"
          ],
          "satuan.original": "kilo"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/project_id/locations/global/agent/intents/2c65093b-b302-44ec-b4b6-03f3eff3c203",
      "displayName": "tambah kategori"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 2335
    },
    "languageCode": "id",
    "sentimentAnalysisResult": {
      "queryTextSentiment": {
        "score": 0.4,
        "magnitude": 0.4
      }
    }
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE, State: URL_UNREACHABLE, Reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx, HTTP status code: 500."
  },
  "outputAudio": "UklGRhAVAwBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAwF0AAIC7AAACABAAZGF0YewUAwDf/wkABQD4/wQACQAAAAUABwADAAcABQADAAYAAgAG... (The content is truncated. Click `COPY` for the original JSON.)",
  "outputAudioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16",
    "synthesizeSpeechConfig": {
      "speakingRate": 1,
      "voice": {
        "customVoice": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "agentId": "1a672368-3fcf-481c-ad18-fdfbd6585bce",
  "agentSettings": {
    "enableAgentWideTts": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that you are not using `agent.add` for the reply so what does the line `agent.add('Ini, ${barang}');` is used for?